# Apple Mac Pro A1186 Power Cable

Tags: mac, mac-pro

I have purchased a Apple Mac Pro A1186 2008 original 2.66GHZ however I power cable is not supplied and I need to purchase one. What cable is it that I need exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's manuals are online: https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1639/en_US/mac_pro_mid2012_ug.pdf but they don't say IEC320C13 on Mac end.

In the US - you're looking for NEMA 5-15P to IEC320C13 like [https://www.amazon.com/C2G-Cables-14719-Universal-IEC320C13/dp/B000067RTS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067RTS)

The MacPro are all standard cables, so get whatever wall configuration you have in your country for any PC with a standard power supply. Basically, any hardware or computer store will be able to hook you up since Mac power supplies are international in terms of 50/60 Hz and 110/220 VAC.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I live in the UK and was wondering if you could point me in the right direction purchase one here. Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: Amazon UK should get you tons of results for IEC320C13 - I really couldn't say other than any hardware store or computer shop could surely help you as well.

Comment: Go anywhere from ASDA to PCWorld. Ask for "A computer IEC mains cable" You could qualify that with "Not a kettle plug" (there's an actual difference but not one that matters in this case, but it will just clear up exactly what shape you need. )

Comment: 'Kettle plugs' have an extra cutout at the bottom, but are otherwise identical. You can actually use a kettle plug in a computer but not vice versa because of that extra cutout.